# migrating an existing app via south

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have the following model -

```
class ToDo(models.Model):

    todo_title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    todo_status = models.IntegerField(choices=TASK_STATUS, null=True, blank=True)
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(OrgStaff, null=True, blank=True, related_name='assigned_to')
    assigned_by = models.ManyToManyField(OrgStaff, null=True, blank=True, related_name='assigned_by')
    assigned_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I then run `python manage.py convert_to_south todoapp` where **todoapp** is the name of the 
app. Then I run `python manage.py migrate todoapp.`

Once that is done, I add another field in the above model -

```
class ToDo(models.Model):

    todo_title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    todo_slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    todo_status = models.IntegerField(choices=TASK_STATUS, null=True, blank=True)
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(OrgStaff, null=True, blank=True, related_name='assigned_to')
    assigned_by = models.ManyToManyField(OrgStaff, null=True, blank=True, related_name='assigned_by')
    assigned_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I do a schemamigation - `python manage.py schemamigration todoapp --auto` and then `python manage.py migrate todoapp` doing this gives the following error -

```
Running migrations for taskbase:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_auto__add_field_todo_todo_slug.
 > taskbase:0002_auto__add_field_todo_todo_slug
KeyError: u'todo_title'
```

**Any idea why I am getting this error?**
I banged my head, but unable to find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that prefixing '**title**' and '**status**' with 'todo_' is causing a collision with the name of the table fields. In fact, in the database Django is naming the fields todoapp_todo_todo_status, and South might just be confused. South does some creative things internally, hence the collision. I would suggest trying:

```
class ToDo(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=TASK_STATUS, null=True, blank=True)
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(OrgStaff, null=True, blank=True, related_name='assigned_to')
    assigned_by = models.ManyToManyField(OrgStaff, null=True, blank=True, related_name='assigned_by')
    assigned_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I wanted to get pedantic, I could also point out that **todoapp** should be called **todos**, but that won't a difference to your project.

Comment: actually I did not have a prefix `todo` initially, the first time I was doing, I was getting an error `KeyError: u'title'` hence I added a prefix. Now this is giving an error.

Comment: I uninstalled South==0.7.3 and upgraded to South==0.8.2 and it worked.